# Creating user story popover

Tags: rally

Could someone help me create a popover that appears on mouse hover to display user story name and project it belongs to. I've created a custom app in rally that displays parent and child stories in a grid. I would like to create a popover when user hover on child story ID to view Name and project information. How can this functionality be added?

```
this.grid = this.down('#gridCnt').add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    id: 'dataGrid',
    showPagingToolbar: true,
    flex: 1,
    store: myCustomStore,
    plugins: ['rallyboardformattedidhoverable'],
    enableBlockedReasonPopover: false,
    columnCfgs: [{
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            text: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
            width: 80,
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
        }, {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
        },
        {
            text: 'Child stories',
            dataIndex: 'Children',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: function(value) {
                var html = [];
                Ext.Array.each(value, function(child) {
                    html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(child) + '">' + child.FormattedID + '</a>' + ' - ' + child.Project);
                });
                return html.join('</br>');
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that should do exactly what you are looking for.  Just add the plugin to your grid config:

```
plugins: ['rallyboardformattedidhoverable'],
getRecord: function(x) {
    return this.view.getRecord(x);
},
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for the response. I added plugin to the grid config but it didn't work.

Comment: You're right- it was throwing an error.  I added a getRecord function to the snippet above which should now work for you.  I filed a defect on this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! It's still throwing an error "Uncaught TypeError: b.record.isSearch is not a functiona.define.bake @ sdk.js:11a.define._showPopover @ sdk.js:11c @ sdk.js:4"

Comment: hmm.  that plugin must assume your model in the store somehow extends from Rally.data.wsapi.Model.  you could either add a function isSearch() that just returns false to your model or else make your model extend from a story model.  otherwise it seems like you might have to write the plugin/popover from scratch...